# How to name each primarykey of column

Tags: mysql, database, naming

I make a table and try to set `primarykey` and need to name it

**For example**

Table name is attendance which have `attendance_code(PK)` , `member_code`,`member_name`,`lecture_code`,exc

Usually how to name it like `AA01`? `AA02`? `AA03`?

Comment: You want to name the attendance_code column name as AA01?

Comment: Do you mean indexes names? Because a table can only have one primary key and it's always going to be name assigned as `PRIMARY`. You can't rename it. But if you meant to rename indexes names apart from a Primary key, that can be done.